# How to check the value of a cookie Testcafe & JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cookies, automated-tests, testcafe

For the purpose of an automated test I need to write a piece of Javascript/Typescript code that on a given website, after giving consent to all cookie, will check two things:

- the presence of a specific cookie (I know the name of this cookie)
- the value of this specific cookie

I started like below but have no idea how to go further:

```
import { Selector, RequestLogger, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';
const getValueOfCookie = ClientFunction(() => document.cookie)
... ?
```

Is anyone able to help me with it?

Comment: Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `document.cookie` is a string, you have to parse it in order to check for the desired cookie and/or get its value.

The following code will return `undefined` if the cookie does not exist:

```
const getValueOfCookie = ClientFunction(() => {
  return document.cookie
    .split('; ')
    .find(row => row.startsWith('cookieName='))
    ?.split('=')[1];
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie for more information.